# Programmatically control individual monitors in a multi monitor setup

Tags: command-line-interface, display

I'm aware of the call
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
which will turn all monitors off.

But my use case is different. I have multiple monitors each with different purposes (presentation, control and communication) The presentation monitor will switch to an alternative input if it is 'disabled/turned off'
This IS something you can do with Windows 10 GUI, Display settings, select display, select in the Multiple Display pulldown 'disabled' (and turn it back on by selecting extend or clone)

The 'displayswitch.exe' command line tool seems to work only for two monitors, not three.

What is the programmatic way of doing what I can do with the GUI? Turn off (disable) the third monitor? Preferable with PowerShell, something like "powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::PostMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)" but able to send that to a specific display port.

Answer (score 0):

This Question was similar:
[How to properly use SetDisplayConfig with multiple monitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136638/how-to-properly-use-setdisplayconfig-with-multiple-monitors/62038912#62038912)

User PuFF1k provided the answer himself on how to use the modern Windows API `SetDisplayConfig` to extend the desktop to all secondary monitors.

I took his answer and formed it into a tiny command line utility.

The source code is freely available on Github: https://github.com/sgrottel/tiny-tools-collection/tree/main/ToggleDisplay

As well as pre-built binaries: https://github.com/sgrottel/tiny-tools-collection/releases/tag/ToggleDisplay-v1.0

In summary:

- User `QueryDisplayConfig` to get possible *paths* connecting your video sources with monitor targets.

  - There are usually many disabled paths, as they include all(?) possibilities for extending or cloning desktop content to different devices
- Change the returned data as you like, switching on or off paths.

  - There are some gotchas, e.g. you should clean all *mode* index references, and later let the API recreate those. I tried to structure and document my code.
- Finally, give the changed data to `SetDisplayConfig`